# Key Error = "see" while running fit_generator() in Tensorflow 2.7.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am facing an error while training my model and running the following code throws a very ambiguous error which I'm unable to comprehend how to solve -:

```
 model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                    validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size)
```

This is the output that i get on running the aforementioned code -:

```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5:
> UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed
> in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports
> generators.   """
> 
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> 
> <ipython-input-96-b22c3ec5e69e> in <module>()

>       3                     epochs=epochs,

>       4                     validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),

> ----> 5                     validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size)

> 
> 2 frames
> 

> <ipython-input-83-d5e1bf945be3> in generate_batch(X, y, batch_size)

>       8             for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(X[j:j+batch_size], y[j:j+batch_size])):

>       9                 for t, word in enumerate(input_text.split()):

> ---> 10                     encoder_input_data[i, t] = input_token_index[word] # encoder input seq

>      11                 for t, word in enumerate(target_text.split()):

>      12                     if t<len(target_text.split())-1:

> 
> KeyError: 'see'
```

Comment: The error happens inside your generator and you did not include the generator's code.

Comment: Need code for  generate_batch suspect that is the cause of the problem

Comment: Could you please provide complete code snippet to reproduce the issue.